# Vector matrix element wise multiplication (by rows) in Julia, efficiently

Tags: julia

I want to  multiply each row of the matrix A by the same vector v. For example

```
A =[1.0 3.0; 1.0 1.0]
v = [1.0, 2.0]
```

I would like to output

```
 [1.0 6.0; 1.0 2.0]
```

So far I am doing:

```
(v.*A')'
```

But I doubt this is computationally efficient given that I transpose a matrix twice.

As a note this question was answered for Matlab (https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243307-vector-matrix-multiplication-row-wise)

Comment: `A.*v'` works for me (Julia v0.6.3)

Comment: Also note, vector by vector multiplications have many flavors. By your examples, you are multiplying each column of `A` by a different scalar according to `v`. Kudos for providing code and examples to make question clear.

Comment: @DanGetz, just as a note,`A.*v'` is, unexpectedly, slightly slower than `(v.*A')'` on my machine (same Julia version).

Comment: One can also do `mapslices(row->v.*row, A, 2)`, which, however, also is slower than what has been mentioned here already.

Comment: @DanGetz, my bad, made a mistake in benchmarks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least the following options:

- `(v.*A')'` (OP's suggestion)
- `v'.*A` (**shortest way**)
- `mapslices(row->v.*row, A, 2)`
- Manual implementation from @AborAmmar's post (**fastest way**)

i.e.

```
function tt(v, A)
    r = similar(A)
    @inbounds for j = 1:size(A,2) 
        @simd for i = 1:size(A,1) 
            r[i,j] = v[j] * A[i,j] # fixed a typo here!
        end
    end 
    r
end
```

**Speed comparison** (in ascending order)

```
julia> @btime tt($v,$A); # @AborAmmar's answer
  38.826 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)

julia> @btime ($v)'.*$A;               
  49.920 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)

julia> @btime (($v).*($A)')';           
  123.797 ns (3 allocations: 336 bytes)                           

julia> @btime mapslices(row->($v).*row, $A, 2);
  25.174 μs (106 allocations: 5.16 KiB)
```

EDIT: Took more careful and faster manual implementation from @AborAmmar's post (replaced old one) and updated speed comparison.

Comment: I've corrected a typo, it is `v[j]` instead of `v[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

What is really awesome about Julia is that you can create your own functions with the same performance as highly optimized builtin functions. Here is another implementation with the same performance (or slightly better) as `(v' .* A)`:

```
function tt1(v, A)
    v'.*A
end

function tt(v, A)
    r = similar(A)
    @inbounds for j = 1:size(A,2) 
        @simd for i = 1:size(A,1) 
            r[i,j] = v[j] * A[i,j]
        end
    end 
    r
end   

const n = 10^4
const A = rand(n,n)
const v = rand(n)

@time tt1(v, A);
@time tt(v, A);

  0.283537 seconds (6 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 19.70% gc time)
  0.235699 seconds (6 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 0.44% gc time)
```

Comment: I referenced and added your version to benchmark in my post.